# UnitTest ASP.NET Application that Requires User to be Logged in

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, authentication

I've got an ASP.NET application that allows users to log on.  Another part of my application uses the UserId (the user must be logged on to access the controller).  How do I fake a logon for unit testing?

Here's how I get the UserId

```
Private _UserId As Guid
    Public ReadOnly Property UserId() As Guid
        Get
            _UserId = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
            Return _UserId
        End Get
    End Property
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is an MVC 3 project.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET WebForms project or an MVC project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a wrapper class for your membership so you can create a Mock to use in your unit tests. code is in C#, i apologize but you'll get my point.

```
    public interface IMyMemberShip
    {
        Guid GetUserId();
    }

    public class MyMemberShip : IMyMemberShip
    {
        public Guid GetUserId()
        {
            return (Guid)System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        }
    }

    public class MockMyMembership : IMyMemberShip
    {
        public Guid GetUserId()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }

    public class AnotherPartOfYourApplication
    {
        IMyMemberShip _myMembership;

        public AnotherPartOfYourApplication(IMyMemberShip myMemberShip)
        {
            _myMembership = myMemberShip;
        }

        public void GetUserIdAndDoSomething()
        {
            var userId = _myMembership.GetUserId();
        }
    }
```

If you are not doing complex stuff in your mock though, i would probably use [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) so you don't need a mock class at all in your unit tests.

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyMemberShip>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetUserId()).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, accept I just made _myMembership have a public setter that I later used to set the IMyMembership.  I've read a few things on moq and still don't get what it does or what that syntax means.  Can you try to explain?

Comment: sure, it is a mocking library for .NET framework. It helps not dealing with complexities of mock classes. In my example above basically i am instantiating my mock object with the interface i want to mock(IMyMemberShip) and then setting up the method i need for my method under test so it returns me dummy data, in this case the new GUID. Then you will pass the moq.Object to the AnotherPartOfYourApplication like you would do with the mock class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` is the method that `FormsAuthentication` uses to setup login information.

Comment: Any idea what I do with that? Just set `Forms.Authentication.SetAuthCookie("myUser", True)` in the `ClassInitialize` section?

Answer (score 0):

You could also call the method that logs in an user at every Unit Test. You could even just add the `UserId() As Guid` return the `Guid` of any user just for testing purposes, unless of course you want to test the "Login" function itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting.  I don't want to touch the original `UserID()` function.  Are you suggesting I use a mocking framework?

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has a blogpost on this:

[IPrincipal user ModelBinder in ASP.NET MVC For easier (unit) testing](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx)

It is not totally what your looking for, but it could bring you up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write own Fake ASP.NET Membership Provider or to try use [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) to emulate ASP.NET environment.